# Why are these two different reversing double linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

To reverse the doubly linked list, What is the difference between these two codes?
Isn't it the same as changing the next and previous pointers?

```
void reverse(Node **head_ref) 
{ 
    Node *temp = NULL; 
    Node *current = *head_ref; 

    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        temp = current->prev; 
        current->prev = current->next; 
        current->next = temp;             
        current = current->prev; 
    } 

    if(temp != NULL ) 
        *head_ref = temp->prev; 
} 

void reverse(Node **head_ref) 
{ 
    Node *temp = NULL; 
    Node *current = *head_ref; 

    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        temp = current->next;
        current->next; = current->prev; 
        current->prev = temp;             
        current = current->next; 
    } 

    if(temp != NULL ) 
        *head_ref = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: The order in which you perform the swap doesn't really matter so long as you end up reversing all nodes. Does this have a singular root node, like a ring structure, or a head and a tail that are separate?

Comment: the 1st reverse method is likely starting at the end and reversing the list by setting the current node to the previous node. The 2nd reverse method does the opposite; likely starting at the beginning of the list, and setting the current node to the next node. Regardless which way you reverse the list, the result is the same.

Comment: The second one traverses the list in the wrong direction, so it won't work. It would work if you started from the tail instead of the head.

Comment: Consider using *existing* C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Read also a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)...

Comment: Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your C++ code to get no warnings, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the runtime behavior of your executable.

Comment: The second one will also not compile ;) `current->next; = current->prev; `

Answer (score 1):

When you swap two references, you can indeed choose with which one to start, i.e. which one to copy to a `temp` variable.

So the following two pieces of code achieve the swap successfully:

```
    temp = current->prev; 
    current->prev = current->next; 
    current->next = temp;
```

And (if you remove the semi-colon you have halfway):

```
    temp = current->next; 
    current->next = current->prev; 
    current->prev = temp;
```

However, your second code block should then continue just like the first code block. You must follow the `prev` link (as before the swap it was the `next` link). So in the second version you should change:

```
    current = current->next;
```

to:

```
    current = current->prev;
```

Still, the problem in the second code is then that at the end of each iteration, your `temp` reference is equal to the `current` reference, and will be null when the loop exits. So that makes it impossible to set the head pointer correctly after the loop exits.

So you should really stick to the first version.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you give feed-back?